# How to randomly name file when using find exec in a bash script?

Tags: bash, random, find

When it comes to quickly converting a bunch of files and randomly renaming them I use a pretty simple way to do so with a for loop:

```
for i in *; do convert [...] $i ../output/$RANDOM.jpg; done
```

Easy as that. The details what imagemagick does here aren't important here. It works as intended. It's just about how to handle the bash stuff.

Now my current case the folder does not only contain photos, it also does contain subfolders with other photos themself. Expected behavior is again that all photos are randomly renamed and the output files are merged in a single folder.

Since I don't know a way to recursively loop with for, I use a find construct here.

```
find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.png" \) -exec convert [...] {} ../output/$RANDOM.jpg  \;
```

**Problem is $RANDOM does only get called once**, so it stays the same over the whole process and the images get overwritten again and again. So in fact the output folder does only one image, the one that got processed the last.

So the question is:
**How do I get the $RANDOM variable to change with each new file?**

Kind regards!

Comment: If you call `$RANDOM` you get at most 32768 unique filenames. Chances are you will overwrite a previous file well before that. You might want to use something like `tempfile` instead.

Comment: You could do `-exec bash -c ...`

Comment: Are you using a reasonably modern version of `bash`  (4.0 or later, so released in the last decade or so)?

Comment: Does it matter that you are renaming PNG's to `$RANDOM.jpg`?

Answer (score 4):

Throw it into a loop.

```
find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.png" \) -type f -print0 |
  while read -d '' -r f 
  do convert [...] "$f" ../output/$RANDOM.jpg  # copied mostly from your find above
  done
```

The `-print0` and `read -d ''` are unnecessary if you never have embedded newlines in your filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `find` at all; just use the `globstar` option.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.jpg **/*.png; do
  convert [...] "$i" ../output/$RANDOM.jpg
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a shell loop as detailed in the other answers, but it's still useful to know how to run arbitrary shell code like `$RANDOM` in a `find -exec` command. You do it by running a shell:

```
find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.png" \) \
    -exec bash -c 'convert [...] "$1" "../output/$RANDOM.jpg"' _ {} \;
```